# Could a Schengen visa refusal be because of cancelled accommodation?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

Edit 2: I have read the answer in the linked duplicate. I however do not understand if in my case it is a serious concern or only a concern related to accomodation (as it was purely touristic purpose). And also the fact that they haven't checked any other boxes and only the one i mentioned. I'm unable to think of any other reason as we completely satisfy all other requirements including more than required money in bank accounts, stable jobs, leave approvals etc. And also given that I've never had a visa issue before. I still hold a valid USA visa.

Myself and my husband applied for a Schengen visa with the French embassy in Bangalore, India.

Our plan was to visit Paris for 10 days and spend the time entirely doing touristic things and sight seeing. We have submitted all the necessary documents along with hotel and flights. However, after submitting the application, our hotel was cancelled due to the fact that they don't accept debit cards but only accept credit cards.

So at the time of visa processing the hotel accommodation we had given was already cancelled. The result of our application is a visa refusal. Could the hotel cancellation be the exact reason for refusal? The reason embassy gave is:

> "The information submitted regarding the justification of purpose and
> the conditions intended to stay were not reliable".

I have previously obtained a Schengen visa and I have also traveled to many countries including the USA, the UK etc. This is my first visa refusal and I can't help but think it's strongly due to the hotel cancellation.

Should we immediately reapply with a new hotel accommodation? Or should we just wait and try another time?

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the question tagged because, the refusal letter has multiple options. And our letter was only checked for the above mentioned reason. Please also note that below two reasons are different:.

> "Justification for the purpose and conditions of intended stay was not provided".
>
> "The information submitted regarding the justification of purpose and the conditions intended to stay were not reliable".

Comment: Please also read the answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: I have read the answer in the linked duplicate. I however do not understand if in my case it is a serious concern or only a concern related to accomodation (as it was purely touristic purpose). And also the fact that they haven't checked any other boxes and only the one i mentioned. I'm unable to think of any other reason as we completely satisfy all other requirements including more than required money in bank accounts, stable jobs, leave approvals etc. And also given that I've never had a visa issue before. I still hold a valid USA visa.

Comment: This refusal reason isn't just about hotel accommodations. It's about much more serious problems with the application. If you're 100% sure your application contained everything necessary for an approval, then you can try appealing via the instructions in your refusal letter. Otherwise, you should see the answer to the linked duplicate.